# printf Ignores Escape Sequence

Tags: escaping, printf, xargs

This command works fine:

```
printf "\e[1;34m%.3d\e[0m\n" 42
```

Output is bold as expected.

However, if I use this kind of escape sequence in this command (using `\e`):

```
$ sudo cat /etc/wireguard/nl1.conf | grep PrivateKey | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs printf "\e[1;34m%s\e[0m\n"
e[1;34mPqyfQ3CtdcoCwgQjW8iGbypofi4TUyJSS5PmVa67sPCTS=e[0m
```

I did not expect this output, but if I input instead the following (using `\33` escape sequence):

```
$ sudo cat /etc/wireguard/nl1.conf | grep PrivateKey | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs printf "\33[1;34m%s\33[0m\n"
PqyfQ3CtdcoCwgQjW8iGbypofi4TUyJSS5PmVa67sPCTS=
```

Which is in bold, thus expected.

My question is why `printf` would accept `\e` in the very first command above, but not in my second command.